# Levenshtein for multiple words on multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, levenshtein-distance

I'm trying to make search a bit more friendly and wanted to exploit the `Levenshtein` distance. This works great but if a value in a column has a length of 25 characters long, the distance to only 3 characters is too far. In this case, it performs worse than the `LIKE` method. I solved this by splitting all words into their own rows using `regexp_split_to_table`. This is nice, but it's still not working if I have multiple words as input.

For example:

Let the data look as following

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one two | three |
| 2 | two | one |
| 3 | horse | tree |
| 4 | house | three |

using `regexp_split_to_table` would transform this to

| id | col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one |
| 1 | two |
| 1 | three |
| 2 | one |
| 2 | two |
| 2 | two |
| 3 | horse |
| 3 | tree |
| 4 | house |
| 4 | three |

If I search for `one tree`, I'd like to compare `one` with each word but also compare `tree` with each word and then order by the sum of both distances.

I have no idea where to start. I also do not know if this is the best approach to do this (it seems somewhat excessive but I'm also not an expert). Maybe I'm also overthinking this. I'd appreciate a hint into the right direction :).

Comment: It appears that you are trying to reinvent the wheel: Postgres supports text based searching. See [Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html).

Comment: @Bohemian I don't know how I can not have found this through google :| Thanks a lot!